# Unable to remove disable property from radio buttons on click of another radio button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in which all the radio buttons are disabled except the first radio button in every row. I want if someone clicks on first radio button then all the radio buttons next to that becomes selectable. below is my code but its not responding well.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr td').not(':nth-child(2)').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled',true);
    $('tr td'):find('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='radio' id='Q6x1_8'>Click<p>
<table border='1'>

<tr>
<td>Test1</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test2</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test3</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test4</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test5</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test6</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use browser console to look at errors! fix your syntax and code works

Answer (score 0):

You have type error in :find() jquery second line

```
//not :find()
$('tr td'):find('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('disabled');
});

// .find()
$('tr td').find('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can Find  Error at your Code

**If It is Not Typo then**

```
  `$('tr td'):find('input[type=radio]')`
```

Replace

```
$('tr td').find('input[type=radio]')
```

Working Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5ZAJk/

Comment: what do you mean `Reference to Jquery is Missing ` ?